# Socket IO client should be globally available error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, socket.io, nuxt.js, laravel-echo

I am using nuxt/laravel api with laravel-echo-server and socket.io-client.

When I use it this way:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
if (process.client) {
  window.io = require('socket.io-client')
  window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'socket.io',
     host: 'http://seekers-backend.com:6001',
     auth: { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer-token' } }
  })
}
```

And then use `window.Echo.private().listen()`.... it works perfectly..

But when I try to declare it within data property I get error because that is rendered on server side... How can I use `socket.io-client` on server side rendering or how can I declare it on client side since I need access to `getters` for Bearer token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the way that works for unknown reason :D

import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

```
if (process.client) {
  window.io = require('socket.io-client')
}
```

And then

```
mounted() {
  let echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://seekers-backend.com:6001',
    auth: { headers: { Authorization: this.token } }
  })
  echo.private('user.' + this.$auth.user.id)
  .listen('MessageEvent', (e) => {
    // Do stuff
  })
}
```